# How do I upload a csv file using google forms and insert the data into a spreadsheet template or into a mysql database using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

How do I upload a csv file and read the data and insert it into a spreadsheet template or  MySql database using apps script

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial#section2) on this subject ?  Maybe it will meet your requirements.